# Spring framework upgrade to 5

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to upgrade Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE to latest spring version 5.0.6.RELEASE. After changing version in my pom.xml it is showing error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;

It's working perfectly fine with 4.0.1.RELEASE.

My pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Joda TIme dependency for date and time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and servletContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c='http://www.springframework.org/schema/c' xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not updated the version of your spring security packages

```
<version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
```

That is why the issue occurs. You need to use

```
<version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
```

[image: Spring versions]

See a similar question posted on the same error

[Parsing applicationContext.xml renders a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. Could this be caused by dependency issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754982/parsing-applicationcontext-xml-renders-a-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-could-th)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE does not support Spring 5.0.0 or greater.
Spring Security 5.0.0 has support for Spring Framework 5.0.0 or greater.

Checkout  **What’s New in Spring Security 5.0 ?** here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#new

Also Spring’s logging setup has been revised for Spring 5. So you **don't need to exclude commons-logging**.
Checkout the logging section here

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/overview.html

Do the below changes and your app with work like a charm.

**Note**: You could also use Spring Security 5.0.5.RELEASE

```
<!-- Spring Core -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>        
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring MVC -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring security -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of spring security from 3.1.3.RELEASE to 5.0.5.RELEASE. Add spring security version in properties file so that you don't miss to change it in future.

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.springframework.security-version>5.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE, This version has support for all and you may add this dependency to your pom.xml file will be look like this ..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring WEB MVC -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```